# Schwarzschild Orbits Perihelion and Aphelion

Tags: general-relativity

In Schwarzschild space-time, one can find the perihelion and aphelion of the non-circular orbits from the roots of the equation:
$$(E^{2} - 1)r^{3} + 2Mr^{2} - L_{z}r + 2ML_{z} = 0.$$

My questions is, how does one guarantee that this would yield 2 positive roots and 1 negative? Conditions can easily be written down, but how does one justify these from theoretical point of view?

Any pointers and suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Why assume there is a negative root ?

Comment: Are you familiar with the conditions for real valued, simple, double and triple roots of [cubic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Algebraic_solution) ?

Comment: I am familiar with the conditions, yes, but how do the values of E, M, and L_z ensure that these conditions are satisfied?

Comment: A cubic function has either one real and two complex roots, or three real roots. In these three real roots, two of them have to be r_p and r_a, and the third one has to be irrelevant, so it needs to be negative.

Comment: It is possible to have the expression with a double or triple root, so that $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ could equal $(x-r_1)^3$ or $(x-r_1)^2(x-r_2)$ and so the third root is not necessarily negative.  I would also be wary of saying a negative root was irrelevant - this is a physics model, and I'd intuitively expect all three roots to have some significance.  I would not expect a negative root for a physical system when I know $r \ge 0$, instead I'd expect a double root or a triple root as a solution.

Comment: Okay, so if there is no negative root, and there is no degenerate roots, what is the significance of all three roots?

Comment: Where did you find this equation? A textbook or an open access  source, if possible